# Java stream, get map of lists of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Trying to get a map of lists using java 8. I have array of predifined titles:

```
String[] myStringArray = {"TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3"};
```

And a list of some Pages objects (`List<String>`).

I need to create a map of lists of objects with keys from the predefined array if the value from this array was found on the page. The result should be like:

```
{TITLE1=[page1, page2, page3], TITLE2=[page3, page4, page5]}
```

(let's assume that TITLE3 was not found in Page list)

My code:

```
Arrays.stream(myStringArray)
        .map(title -> page
                .stream()
                .filter(p -> isPageContainsTitle(p, title))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e, Function.identity()));
```

As a result i get Map of lists with list in key instead of value from myStringArray:

```
{[page1, page2, page3]=[page1, page2, page3], [page3, page4, page5]=[page3, page4, page5]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure array has unique titles and then use `Collectors.toMap`

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(myStringArray)
            .map(title -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(title,
                    pages.stream().filter(page -> isPageContainsTitle(page,title)).collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

And as @Naman suggested you can avoid the intermediate `map` operation

```
Map<String, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(myStringArray) 
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity() 
                                        ,title -> pages.stream()
                                                       .filter(page -> isPageContainsTitle(page, title))
                                                       .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: Page is a String object, and i can  check it only with contains method (wrapped in my isPageContainsTitle)

Comment: can you show the sample example with `Page` and how are you checking title ?

Comment: It just like String page = "TEXT,TITLE,TEXT,ONE,TWO" and "TITLE" can be anywere in string. page.contains("TITLE") Also i need map values ONLY from array

Comment: Or simply `Map<String, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(myStringArray)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                        title -> pages.stream().filter(page -> isPageContainsTitle(page, title))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())));` without the need of `map` operation. Though `groupingBy` with a change in the `isPageContainsTitle` implementation might just be cleaner.

Comment: Thank you @Naman and yes i agree `groupingBy` will be cleaner approach

Answer (score 2):

Below code should work for you:

```
package com.shree.test;

import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class StreamTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myStringArray = {"TITLE1", "TITLE2", "TITLE3"};
        List<String> pages = new ArrayList<>();
        pages.add("TEXT,TITLE2,TEXT,ONE,TWO");
        pages.add("TEXT,TITLE1,TEXT,ONE,TWO");
        pages.add("TEXT,TITLE2,TEXT,ONE,TWO");
        pages.add("TEXT,TITLE2,TEXT,TITLE3,TWO");
        pages.add("TEXT,TITLE3,TEXT,ONE,TWO");



         Map<Object, Object> titleMap = getTitleMap(myStringArray, pages);

         titleMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
    }

    private static Map<Object, Object> getTitleMap(String[] myStringArray, List<String> pages) {
        Map<Object, Object> titleMap = Arrays.asList(myStringArray).stream()
            .map(
                    (title)->{
                        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(title, pages.stream()
                                .filter((page)->page.contains(title))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
                    }
                )
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry->entry.getKey(), entry->entry.getValue()));
        return titleMap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So

```
 e->e
```

and

```
  Function.identity()
```

are and should be equivalent.

What you really want is a flatMap:

```
  Arrays.stream(myStringArray)
                .flatMap(title -> pages
                        .stream()
                        .filter(p -> isPageContainsTitle(p, title))
                        .map( p -> new Tuple(t, p)) 
                 )
                 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy( t -> t._1, t -> t._2));
```

We want flatMap because we may get back 0, 1 or many Tuples of (title, page)

This assumes you have a Tuple class, I'm modelling one based on Scala's Tuple2.

Note, I have not tested this code.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see to do this with the separate objects it to map them to a two element array of types `String` and `List<Page>` to an array and then use those entries to build the map.

The `Object[]{}` array will contain the title and the list.  This was the only way to preserve the two values across nested streams.

I later cast them to create a `Map<String,List<Page>>`

This requires no modification of your existing data structures.

```java
 Map<String, List<Page>> map = Arrays.stream(myStringArray)
            .map((String title) -> new Object[] {title,
                                       page.stream().filter(
                                   (Page p) -> isPageContainsTitle(p, title)).collect(
                                    Collectors.toList())})
            .filter(arr->arr[1] != null)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> (String)arr[0], arr -> (List<Page>)arr[1]));
```

There is a type safety warning in the final List cast but it should be okay.